# Cant log in to mailgun account. "The CSRF session token is missing."

Tags: authentication, csrf

When I try to log in to our mailgun account I get the error message

> The CSRF session token is missing.

I cannot start a support ticket without logging in. When I try to recover our account, it leads to an invalid url. 
Any suggestions? Can anyone put me through to the support desk of mailgun?

Thanks

wf51

Comment: Sounds like someone deployed to production and introduced a bug. Mailgun is fairly responsive on twitter, and log issues and their resolution there:
ttps://twitter.com/Mail_Gun I would recommend tweeting your problem @ them/checking their twitter account to see if they're already aware of it, and then waiting patiently until their next release

Answer (score 1):

Use Firefox. In Chrome and Safari I have the same problem, but Firefox works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Works on Chrome 77.0.3865.90  but does not work on Firefox 60.9.0 for me. Just tried today